# Is there a way of setting Node.js cli options as default?

Tags: node.js

I'd like be able to define a set of default [CLI options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html) for every npm script.

What I want to achieve is to ensure that every npm script of a given project runs with the CLI option `--unhandled-rejections=strict`.

Is there a formal mechanism for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this on a common Linux System you should be able to set it within your .npmrc file inside your home directory.

Just add a line

**unhandled-rejections=strict;**

to your /home/[username]/.npmrc

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. At least this doesn't work for me when set in `.npmrc`:

`--unhandled-rejections=strict`

Comment: So far, only `export NODE_OPTIONS="--unhandled-rejections=strict"` worked.

Comment: My project uses `.yarnrc` and I tried a few variantions

`npm_package_NODE_OPTIONS --unhandled-rejections=strict`

`NODE_OPTIONS --unhandled-rejections=strict`

`--unhandled-rejections strict`

`unhandled-rejections strict`